# Files with .mysql extension

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know what a file with a .mysql extension is and what can be done on it. I recently downloaded a database with a .mysql extension and I do not know what to do with it. All I am used to are .sql files.

Comment: did you check if it isn't just a textfile containing sql statements? some call them .sql, some .txt, some .mysql... doesn't really make a difference

Comment: well, I tried opening it with gedit but it could not read it... I also changed the file extension to .txt and .sql still the same story.

Comment: since you're on linux, what does the file command tell you? type "file yourfile.mysql" into the console. it should print out what type of file it is

Comment: @burntblark try to open it with hex editor. Sometimes there is an identifier at the beginning or at the end of file. Or perhaps the content will be easily recognizable to you. Another guess: it can be zipped or gzipped sql file. Try to unzip/ungzip.

Comment: @Gryphius This is what it printed out: "File 4.23 supports only 4 version magic files. `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc' is version 7"

Comment: ok, seems that your file magic installation is broken. where did you download the file, is it somewhere public so we could check?

Comment: @Karolis I tried opening it with the Archive Manager but it says "error extracting file"

Comment: Okay @all, thanks for your help, I found out the file was corrupt. I downloaded it again and it is actually a file with SQL statements (a dump of the database). My apologies.